# ruby pattern for generating geometrically expanding objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given three arrays of unique ids, where the goal is to create individual identifiers that join each member of the three arrays

```
array_a = [1,2]
array_b = [43,44,47]
array_c = [3,15]
```

this implies 2 * 3 * 2 individual identifiers (seperated by underscores for legibility purposes):

```
1_43_3, 1_43_15, 1_44_3, 1_44_15, 1_47_3, 1_47_15, 2_43_3, 2_43_15, 2_44_3, 2_44_15, 2_47_3, 2_47_15
```

Is there a ruby method that allows to create such a set, i.e. to multiply arrays of arrays ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `product` method

Input

```
array_a = [1,2]
array_b = [43,44,47]
array_c = [3,15]
```

Program

```
p array_a.product(array_b,array_c).map{|x|x.join("_")}
```

Output

```
["1_43_3", "1_43_15", "1_44_3", "1_44_15", "1_47_3", "1_47_15", "2_43_3", "2_43_15", "2_44_3", "2_44_15", "2_47_3", "2_47_15"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, but it's fairly trivial to implement with a couple of loops:

```
array_a = [1,2]
array_b = [43,44,47]
array_c = [3,15]

combined = array_a.flat_map do |a|
  array_b.flat_map do |b|
    array_c.map do |c|
      [a, b, c].join("_")
    end
  end
end
```

Edit - although the solution using `product` from @Rajagopalan is very neat.

Comment: Yes, `product` avenue from @Rajagopalan is neat. This one has a more 'oviousness' to the code.  Will test performance on these two...

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just shedding light on the two valid answers provided.

Running a performance test in the following manner:

```
time = Benchmark.measure {
  code_to_test
}
puts time
```

with four data sets:

1. the first an array with sizes 10x10x10,
2. the second an array with sizes 20x20x20, which is almost an order of magnitude greater than the former, then
3. a third array with sizes 30x30x30. and a final
4. 40x40x40, almost another order of magnitude.

The product method returns for each array

```
   user     system      total        
0.002692   0.000340   0.003032 
0.057010   0.003608   0.060618 
0.078614   0.010978   0.089592 
0.217555   0.015326   0.232881
```

while the nested flat_map array returns

```
0.002562   0.000145   0.002707 
0.077731   0.001857   0.079588 
0.085422   0.001829   0.087251 
0.263692   0.005506   0.269198
```

rather indistinguisahble, even at relatively high numbers.

Comment: This is great! I expect under the hood they're doing exactly the same thing.